# База Данных , Добавляется лишние данные откуда незнаю

Tags: android, sqlite

// БД

```
public class DataHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DB_NAME = "dc.db";

private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

private static final String TABLE_HERO = "heroes";
private static final String DC_NAME = "dc_name";
private static final String DC_FAVORITE = "favorite";


public DataHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String sql = "create table " + TABLE_HERO + " (" +
            BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            DC_NAME + " TEXT," +
            DC_FAVORITE + " INTEGER);";

    db.execSQL(sql);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

public void saveHero(ArrayList<Hero> list) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
    for (Hero hero : list) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DC_NAME, hero.getName());
        database.insert(TABLE_HERO, null, values);
    }
    database.close();

}

public ArrayList<Hero> getHeroId() {
    ArrayList<Hero> list = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase database = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_HERO, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Hero hero = new Hero();
        hero.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID)));
        hero.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DC_NAME)));
        list.add(hero);
    }
    cursor.close();
    database.close();
    return list;
}}
```

// MoDel

```
public class Hero {

private String name;
private int id;

public Hero (String name){

    this.name = name;
}

public Hero() {

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}



public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}}
```

//MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView idHeroText;
DataHelper dataHelper;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    idHeroText = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.idHeroText);

    dataHelper = new DataHelper(this);

    heroAdd();

    Log.e("Log" , "BD = " + dataHelper.getHeroId());
    ArrayList<Hero> hero = dataHelper.getHeroId();

    idHeroText.setAdapter(new PhraseAdapter(this, hero));


}


public void heroAdd (){
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        String name = " " + i;
        Hero hero = new Hero(name);
        list.add(hero);
        dataHelper.saveHero(list);
    }

}}
```

//Adapter

```
public class PhraseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<Hero> list;
private LayoutInflater inflater;


public PhraseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Hero> list) {

    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.list = list;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Hero getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {


    final ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        viewHolder.idname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtV_EN);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {

        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final Hero phrase = list.get(position);
    viewHolder.idname.setText(String.valueOf(phrase.getName()));

    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView idname;
}}
```

Comment: Я добавляю 3 Данных а Добавляется 6 почему

Comment: Мой Лог : 08-04 21:04:07.335 14027-14027/com.mnd.testbd E/Log: BD = [com.mnd.testbd.Hero@4265a110, com.mnd.testbd.Hero@42678e28, com.mnd.testbd.Hero@42678e78, com.mnd.testbd.Hero@42678ec8, com.mnd.testbd.Hero@42678f18, com.mnd.testbd.Hero@42678f68]

Comment: А в Адаптере Показывает 1 1 2 Потом мои Цифры 1 2 3

Comment: 6 так как вы добавляете масив в цикле (сохраняете в базу). вот и получается 3 итерации (1+2+3=6). вынесете запись масива из цикла

Answer (score 1):

6 так как вы добавляете масив в цикле (сохраняете в базу). вот и получается 3 итерации (1+2+3=6). вынесете запись масива из цикла.
касательно адаптера, - напишите подробней, так как не понятно что имеете в виду

Comment: Спасибо за ответ ..... я оказывается сохранял в цикле ..... теперь все работает нормально